# Making multiple graphs from individual lines in R, iterating through a dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset that looks like this:

```
> averages
            compound     control.0   control.30  surgery.0   surgery.30
1.                 A      3.609958  3.578200086   3.556325  3.669107598
2.                 B      4.984090  4.798330495   4.965342  4.812247664
```

I want to make a graph for only compound A that plots two lines- one connecting (0, control.0) to (30, control.30) and one that plots (0, surgery.0) to (30, surgery.30). I also have 200 compounds so I would ideally like to be able to have the program go down the list and spit out a graph for each compound without me manually going in and changing the line number. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! To improve your chances of getting an answer it is important that you have [thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and show us [what you have tried yourself](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/156810/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

For two line segments per graph, use this:

```
with(subset(averages, compound=="A"), plot(c(0,30,NA,0,30),c(control.0,control.30,NA,surgery.0,surgery.30), type="l"))
```

Then change the subset condition to create a loop.